# Push a multi array to array?

Tags: php

```
$galleryData = [];  
foreach($input['gallery'] as $galleryImg) {


}
```

I want to push in the galleryData array, a keyed array.

How can I do this?

I've tried:

```
$galleryData[] = ['name'=>$galleryImg['file']['name'], 'comment'=> $galleryImg['file']['comment'], 'youtube'=> $galleryImg['file']['youtube']];
```

But no luck.

Comment: Why don't you wrap it in array()?

Answer (score 1):

```
$galleryData[] = array(
    'name'=>$galleryImg['file']['name'], 
    'comment'=> $galleryImg['file']['comment'],       
    'youtube'=> $galleryImg['file']['youtube']
);
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$galleryData = array_map(function($a) {return $a['file'];},$input['gallery']);
```

If there are other keys, try this variant:

```
$allowedKeys = array("name","comment","youtube");
$galleryData = array_map(function($a) use ($allowedKeys) {
    return array_intersect_key($a['file'],array_flip($allowedKeys));
},$input['gallery']);
```

Taking into consideration your update, there's no longer such a shortcut. Try this:

```
$galleryData = array_map(function($a) {
    return array(
        "comment"=>$a['comment'],
        "name"=>$a['file']['name'],
        "youtube"=>$a['file']['youtube']
    );
},$input['gallery']);
```

Comment: Thanks. Surely it's easy to use user1281385 answer? Which is better processing wise?

Comment: This one uses a built-in function (`array_map`) to perform the loop, making it more efficient because it's lower-level.

Comment: Thanks. There was a mistake in my original question. 'comment'=> $galleryImg['file']['comment'] is actually 'comment'=> $galleryImg['comment']. Without the file. How can I use your code with this?